# Running software-sources results in Python error (LMDE 3)

Tags: python, debian-based, cinnamon

I am in need to run the Software Sources GUI (no, my job *cannot* be completed through `apt` or `aptitude`). Since the window would never load if I navigated from the launcher, I decided to see what happens if I were to run it from the command line:

```
jason@jason-mint:~$ software-sources 
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 48
    def async(func):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The function in the file `mintSources.py` looks like this:

```
# Used as a decorator to run things in the background
def async(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper
```

At the very top, the shebang says: `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Since my default Python is Python 2.7, I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python` to see what happens, only to have a new error this time:

```
jason@jason-mint:/etc/apt$ software-sources 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 6, in <module>
    import configparser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Which means it failes in `import configparser`, clearly an indication that python2.7 (my default) will not work. To clarify, I have *both* Python2 *and* Python3 available:

```
jason@jason-mint:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
jason@jason-mint:~$ python2
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
jason@jason-mint:~$ python3
Python 3.7.3rc1 (default, Mar 13 2019, 11:01:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
jason@jason-mint:~$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Some system info if it helps:

```
jason@jason-mint:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
buster/sid
jason@jason-mint:~$ uname -r
4.19.0-4-amd64
```